# Newline in constant and ; Expected

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm currently working on school assignment which is to create a simple e-commerce website.
Having Problems with the codes for Updating Customer Details:

```
 public partial class UpdateCust : System.Web.UI.Page
{
public string UFlag = "F"; public string strUserId;
static readonly string scriptSuccessUpdate = "<script language=\"javascript\">\n" +
"alert(\"Update Successful - Please surf to other pages to shop\");\n </script>”;
```

Getting 2 Errors on

"alert(\"Update Successful - Please surf to other pages to shop\");\n ”;

1. Newline in constant
2. ; expected

The codes were provided by the tutor to be used in the update button, but I'm not familiar with them. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Look at your closing quote after `</script>`. It's not an ASCII double-quote...

Comment: You using bad quote at the end of last line ... you using `”` instead of `"`

Comment: Common copy past issue, remove/retype your last double quote.

Answer (score 2):

```
static readonly string scriptSuccessUpdate = "<script language=\"javascript\">\n" +
            "alert(\"Update Successful - Please surf to other pages to shop\");\n </script>";
```

the last quote is diff please correct it

Comment: The last quote is just a different character than `"`.

Comment: I think, that he not missed anything ... he used bad quote only `”` instead of `"`

Answer (score 1):

This is because use of wrong quotes symbol:

```
static readonly string scriptSuccessUpdate = "<script language=\"javascript\">\n" + "alert(\"Update Successful - Please surf to other pages to shop\");\n </script>”;
```

You need to use this :

```
static readonly string scriptSuccessUpdate = "<script language='javascript'>alert('Update Successful - Please surf to other pages to shop')</script>";
```

check out the correct way to use quotes. When to use **double quotes** `"` and when to use **single quote** `'`

 That was the only problem with your code.

Answer (score -1):

You Use **”** .

Correct Code :
static readonly string scriptSuccessUpdate = "\n" +
            "alert(\"Update Successful - Please surf to other pages to shop\");\n ";

Comment: review your answer, then edit the code format and insert problem description, thanks, this answer is horrible